# Laravel4 Doesnt show old::input()

Tags: session, laravel-4

New to laravel4 and cant get the basic things to work such as:

```
function doRegister() {

    try {

        $email = Input::get('email');
        $type = Input::get('type'); // <-- Data from radio button

        # Check if email exists
        if ( User::where('email','=',$email)->count() > 0 ) {
            # This account already exists
            throw new Exception( 'This email already in use by someone else.' );
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->with('message', $e->getMessage() );
    }


}
```

Now on the `homepage` controller (which is `/`) I cant read the value of `Input::old('type');`
and it returns empty. How come?

Comment: How did you use `Input::old(...)` in your `view` ? Do you get `message` after redirect ?

Comment: I do get `message` but on the controller when i `echo Input::old('type')` its empty

Comment: Check the session using `dd(Session::get('type'))` and make sure it's there.

Comment: Nope...it's `NULL` maybe it has something to do with throwing an exception and passing `->withInput()->with('message...` ?

Comment: Then it's not in the session, can you use `Input::flash();` before you redirect to home page and then try to get the old input ? Also, you may check session data using `dd(Session::all())` on your home page.

Comment: I did `Input::flash();` right before `Redirect::to` and did a `dd(Session::all());` on the homepage and that's what I got: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=qpf9zp&s=8#.Uz0bxq2SxRc

For some reason, the `old` entry contains message

Comment: OH WAIT, I had another redirect before it without the ->withInput()...so It didnt pass! I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it and try my answer, it's better and the right way to validate unique email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function doRegister()
{
    $rules = array('email' => 'required|email|unique:users');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()>withErrors($validator);
    }
    else {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $type = Input::get('type');
        // Register...
    }
}
```

You can retrieve validation errors using:

```
$errors->first('email');
```